# Why use const int parameter when overloading the subscript operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I am new to C++ so can you please explain why/when should I use this

```
int & MyArray::operator[] (const int i)
{
    return arr[i];
}
```

instead of this

```
int & MyArray::operator[] (int i)
{
    return arr[i];
}
```

Comment: It's just good practice. If you're not going to modify the value of the parameter, then you might as well make it const.

Comment: @AliAlamiri as long as you don't do it in the function declaration, because that would be misleading.

Comment: @juanchopanza: why would it mislead you? By your answer you obviously know what it means.

Comment: @SteveJessop because you don't have to follow suit in the definition. So the declaration may suggest that the parameter is `const`, and the definition can completely ignore it. So the `const` serves no purpose in the declaration. That is why I suggest to avoid the `const` in the function declaration.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I wonder if one could just as well say that the declaration should never name the parameters (`i` in this case), because the definition might use different names and so any name in the declaration is misleading. In practice you do usually want names as proto-documentation. The `const` doesn't document much, but for some types (bizarrely!) it documents that the function doesn't retain a copy of the argument. If it did it would use a non-const parameter and then either `move` or `swap` from it. I probably wouldn't rely on that as a convention myself, though!

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't know I think not making the declaration and the definition the same just adds to the confusion. If I see a parameter declared as const in the definition but not in the declaration, I'd actually hate it. It's just not consistent.

Comment: @AliAlamiri My point is that most users of the code look at the declaration, and not the definition. So I treat the `const` in the definition as an implementation detail that should not be expressed in the declaration. But that is just my personal preference.

Comment: @SteveJessop The parameter name doesn't change the semantics though, but I take your point. I would prefer it if the language *did* distinguish between top-level `const` and non-`const` in declarations, given that it makes a difference in the definition. But things being as they are, I prefer to use the `const` in the definition only, as an implementation detail that may even be changed in the future without notice.

Comment: @juanchopanza: The `const` doesn't change the semantics *of the declaration*, which is the reason it doesn't affect the function signature. I think what's slightly unfortunate (but pretty much unavoidable) is that the parameter list is used in the definition to specify something that doesn't affect the function interface. This creates the desire for declarations that don't match their definitions, to remove the irrelevant cruft. I don't think it would be an improvement over all to make the cruft significant in the declaration too, but I see your point :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: ah, although I suppose we could declare `int &foo(int idx);` and define `int &foo(int idx) [[const int idx]] {`, or some such special syntax to re-define the parameter in the definition. That would avoid confusing anyone (those who expect not to see irrelevant `const` in declarations and those who expect declarations to match definitions) at the cost of being so ugly nobody would use it. Then it would be OK to make the `const` part of the function signature as you want, because we'd have a way to change the implementation detail without changing the interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doesn't make a huge amount of difference!

Some people like to treat parameters as immutable, so they flag them as `const`. In this case it's a stylistic thing.

Comment: It is definitely not a stylistic issue, as there will be an error raised if you try and modify a `const` parameter inside the function body.

Comment: @mfukar - I meant it's stylistic in that it doesn't alter overloading resolution and is more about how you with to treat parameters.

Comment: In that case, here's my +1, sir. :)

Comment: It gives the compiler scope for further optimizations. So to say it doesn't make a huge difference needs to be qualified. You could also say that id does make a HUUUUGE difference. It really depends on the context.

Answer (score 4):

In a function *declaration*, it makes absolutely no difference, because top-level `const`s are ignored.

These two are actually the same declaration, and for that reason, top level `const` in function parameters should be avoided:

```
void foo(int);
void foo(const int); // re-declaration of above function
```

In a function *definition*, it means you cannot change the copy of the argument in your function:

```
void foo(int i) { i++; } // OK
void foo(const int i) { i++; } // Error
```

So, it can be used as an implementation artifact, to express that the local variable is `const`. This gives the compiler more scope to perform optimizations.

Comment: "This may allow the compiler to perform some optimizations." - for a specific example: if the function passes a pointer to `i` into unknown code, then with the `const` the optimizer can rely on the value not changing, which means it doesn't need to clear it out of any register it might be stored in, and if the call to `foo` is inlined with a value of `i` known at compile-time, then uses of the value of `i` after that call to unknown code can use the compile-time value. Without the `const` it can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. It's identical from caller's perspective and just adds visual noise.

The parameter `i` is passed by value and is a plain data type, it is copied, so when you mark it as `const` you are telling the compiler that it cannot change inside the method, but since it is a copy it isn't important at all, and in this specific example you are just using it as an index.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are correct. Use the first one if you want to ensure that the "i" parameter will not be modified in the function, which may be useful if the function is longer/more complicated.
However, in the declaration of the operator do not use const:

```
int& operator[](int i);
```

It is legal to have declaration without const, and definition with it.

Comment: Unless your using the SunStudio compiler when you definitely should make your definition match your declaration.

Answer (score 0):

As a generale rule, anything you do not intend to modify should be `const`

Answer (score 0):

If you not trying to edit your parameter then its better to use `const`.

As far as performance is concerned not much difference. But it safeguards your parameter from editing (**accidentally**) inside function.

```
int & MyArray::operator[] (const int i)
```